# Workaround for Hibernate relationships and SmartGWT RESTDataSources

Tags: hibernate, gwt, datasource, smartgwt

I'm lost with the way I have to implement a ManyToMany relationship defined in Hibernate. In the client-side we're using SmartGWT LGPL version with RESTDataSources working fine against some back-end webservices.

The relationship is made between a typical Role and Permissions. In Rol.class:

```
...
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "ROL_PERMISO", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROL_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PERMISO_ID"))
private Set<Permiso> permisos;
...
```

In the client side I have two 'views'. The first one is for permission's management. The another one is for role management, which has a ListGrid showing roles and a DynamicForm with a permissions CheckBoxTree to select the permissions associated to the role, and other fields like name and description.

How I stablish the relationship between roles and permissions in the DataSources? Any recommended workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching on it I've solved that using nested DataSource:

In Rol DataSource:

```
...
// One to Many relationship
DataSourceField permisos = new DataSourceField("permisos", FieldType.TEXT, locale.permisos());
permisos.setTypeAsDataSource(PermisoDS.getInstance());
...
```

The key is create a DatSourceField and set the type as DataSource. And then, for accessing the data you can use **getAttributeAsRecordArray("permisos")** in a record of Rol DataSource

Hope this help someone!